# Wix update bindingRedirect value

Tags: wix, wix3

I have an installer which needs to change the bindingRedirect value in the app.config. Currently, I have:

```
    <util:XmlFile Id="Config"
      Action="setValue"
      ElementPath="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[\[]@publicKeyToken='89845dcd8080cc91'[\]]/bindingRedirect/@newVersion"
      File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\app.config"
      Value="13.0.0.0"/>
```

but this is throwing an error as it cant find the node. I'm guessing this is because bindingRedirect isn't a child element of assemblyIdentity.

How would I go about updating the newVersion field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the resolution to this problem, should anyone else hit this issue!

```
    <util:XmlFile Id="Config"
      Action="setValue"
      ElementPath="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[\[]assemblyIdentity/@publicKeyToken='89845dcd8080cc91'[\]]/bindingRedirect/@newVersion"
      File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\app.config"
      Value="13.0.0.0"/>
```

and the assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" in the config file needs to be changed to assemblyBinding

Answer (score 0):

Your element path is incorrect. That is not a valid XPath query (with the msi specific escaping). You probably want a leading forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

@JWoodley13 you are my hero, thank you so much for this answer.
To get this working with WiX v4.0.2, I also needed to install the global tools and install the WixToolset.Util.wixext extension too, before I could reference it in the .wixproj as a PackageReference.

On command line:

```
dotnet tool install --global wix --version 4.0.2
wix extension add -g WixToolset.Util.wixext
```

In .wixproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Util.wixext" Version="4.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In `.wxs` file, import the updated wxs and wxs/util namespaces:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">
```

I tweaked the xpath to use the package name too:

```
      <Component Id="ChangeConfig" Guid="18C80C2F-D0CC-486D-A80A-23646BBAB8FF">
        <util:XmlFile Id="Config"
          Action="setValue"
          ElementPath="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[\[]assemblyIdentity/@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]]/bindingRedirect/@newVersion"
          File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\app.config"
          Value="13.0.0.0"/>
      </Component>
```